# Google+ Sign-in API shutdown - Profile.me

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-plus-signin

since Google announced that Google+ Sign-in will be fully deprecated in near future, I just want to confirm that I understand we are not using any of its deprecated features.

Currently in our code I can see that we are only using following two classes:

1. `com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2`
2. `com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfoplus`

Under 1, part of the code we are worried about is

```
public class Me
```

which, as far as I understand, addresses `plus.me` (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide), which is being deprecated.

Under 2, is this class also being deprecated? It seems like the part (or all) of the Google+ profile is contained in there.

Both classes mentioned above are part of the following library version:

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v2-rev77-1.19.0
```

The version of api-client is:

```
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0
```

Many thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Me` class does not appear to be related to the `plus.get` endpoint. The Path specified in the `Me.Get` class is

```
private static final String REST_PATH = "userinfo/v2/me";
```

which specifies the `userinfo` endpoint, rather than the `plus.get` endpoint.

Similarly, although the `Userinfoplus` sure sounds like it is related to the `plus` endpoint, the fields in it appear to match the `userinfo` v2 endpoint. They certainly don't do anything to access the `plus.me` endpoint directly, anyway.